# agrep: only return best match(es)

Tags: r, text, character, string-matching, agrep

I'm using the 'agrep' function in R, which returns a vector of matches.  I would like a function similar to agrep that only returns the best match, or best matches if there are ties.  Currently, I am doing this using the 'sdist()' function from the package 'cba' on each element of the resulting vector, but this seems very redundant.

/edit: here is the function I'm currently using.  I'd like to speed it up, as it seems redundant to calculate distance twice.

```
library(cba)
word <- 'test'
words <- c('Teest','teeeest','New York City','yeast','text','Test')
ClosestMatch <- function(string,StringVector) {
  matches <- agrep(string,StringVector,value=TRUE)
  distance <- sdists(string,matches,method = "ow",weight = c(1, 0, 2))
  matches <- data.frame(matches,as.numeric(distance))
  matches <- subset(matches,distance==min(distance))
  as.character(matches$matches)
}

ClosestMatch(word,words)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RecordLinkage package was removed from CRAN, use stringdist instead:

```
library(stringdist)

ClosestMatch2 = function(string, stringVector){

  stringVector[amatch(string, stringVector, maxDist=Inf)]

}
```

Comment: Package `RecordLinkage` is available on CRAN, again (Version 0.4-9 as of 2016-05-02.

Answer (score 30):

The agrep package uses Levenshtein Distances to match strings. The package RecordLinkage has a C function to calculate the Levenshtein Distance, which can be used directly to speed up your computation. Here is a reworked `ClosestMatch` function that is around 10x faster

```
library(RecordLinkage)

ClosestMatch2 = function(string, stringVector){

  distance = levenshteinSim(string, stringVector);
  stringVector[distance == max(distance)]

}
```

Comment: @DWin. Thanks for the correction. I have edited my answer to correct the spelling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's a great function.  What is the intended purpose of that package?  There may be other functions in there relevant to my project.

Comment: @Zach. Yes. it is likely to contain a lot of functions relevant to your work. There are a lot of vignettes on the CRAN page for this package that you can lookup (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html)

Comment: You can change from distance == max(distance) to which.max(distance)

Comment: Hi I know this is pretty old but I was wondering. Is there a way to extend this function to get a minimal Levenshtein score and `NA` if that minimum is not reached? I have to combine two long vectors of words but it's very likely that in at least 50% of cases, there is no close match...

Comment: The package RecordLinkage has been removed from CRAN because of failures to fix memory problems.

Comment: Package `RecordLinkage` is available on CRAN, again (Version 0.4-9 as of 2016-05-02.

Comment: @SJDS You could wrap the function in an if statement that would only match if a certain max(distance) was reached. I am doing this now.

You could add the cutoff as an argument in the function as well, and include a condition in the function that returns some sort of null value if this cutoff is not reached.