# approximate string matching within single list - r

Tags: r, string-matching, agrep

I have a list in a data frame of thousands of names in a long list. Many of the names have small differences in them which make them slightly different. I would like to find a way to match these names. For example:

```
names <- c('jon smith','jon, smith','Jon Smith','jon smith et al','bob seger','bob, seger','bobby seger','bob seger jr.')
```

I've looked at `amatch` in the `stringdist` function, as well as `agrep`, but these all require a [master list of names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721883/agrep-only-return-best-matches) that are used to match another list of names against.  In my case, I don't have such a master list so I'd like to create one from the data by identifying names with highly similar patterns so I can look at them and decide whether they're the same person (which in many cases they are). I'd like an output in a new column that helps me to know these are a likely match, and maybe some sort of similarity score based on Levenshtein distance or something. Maybe something like this:

```
            names   match      SimilarityScore
1       jon smith     a               9
2      jon, smith     a               8
3       Jon Smith     a               9
4 jon smith et al     a               5
5       bob seger     b               9
6      bob, seger     b               8
7     bobby seger     b               7
8   bob seger jr.     b               5
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: While I don't have a narrow answer (sorry), I would probably start searching in the [natural language processing task view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html).

Comment: It looks like [hierarchical text clustering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21513338/1203041) will do what I'm looking for.

Comment: thanks for the hierarchical text clustering link. language processing looks interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drawing  upon the post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511801/text-clustering-with-levenshtein-distances/21513338#21513338) I have found that hierarchical text clustering will do what I'm looking for.

```
  names <- c('jon smith','jon, smith','Jon Smith','jon smith et al','bob seger','bob, seger','bobby seger','bob seger jr.','jake','jakey','jack','jakeyfied')

# Levenshtein Distance
e  <- adist(names)
rownames(e) <- names
hc <- hclust(as.dist(e))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc,k=3) #the k value provides the number of clusters
df <- data.frame(names,cutree(hc,k=3))
```

The output looks really good if you pick the right number of clusters (three in this case):

```
                       names             cutree.hc..k...3.
jon smith             jon smith                 1
jon, smith           jon, smith                 1
Jon Smith             Jon Smith                 1
jon smith et al jon smith et al                 1
bob seger             bob seger                 2
bob, seger           bob, seger                 2
bobby seger         bobby seger                 2
bob seger jr.     bob seger jr.                 2
jake                       jake                 3
jakey                     jakey                 3
jack                       jack                 3
jakeyfied             jakeyfied                 3
```

However, names are oftentimes more complex than this, and after adding a few more difficult names, I found that the default `adist` options didn't give the best clustering:

```
names <- c('jon smith','jon, smith','Jon Smith','jon smith et al','bob seger','bob, seger','bobby seger','bob seger jr.','jake','jakey','jack','jakeyfied','1234 ranch','5678 ranch','9983','7777')

d  <- adist(names)
rownames(d) <- names
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc,k=6)
```

[image: Cluster2]

I was able to improve upon this by increasing the cost of the substitution value to 2 and leaving the insertion and deletion costs at 1, and ignoring case. This helped to to minimize the mistaken grouping of totally different four character number strings, which I didn't want grouped:

```
d  <- adist(names,ignore.case=TRUE, costs=c(i=1,d=1,s=2)) #i=insertion, d=deletion s=substitution
rownames(d) <- names
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc,k=6
```

[image]

I further fine tuned the clustering by removing common terms such as "ranch" and "et al" using the `gsub` tool in the `grep` package and increasing the number of clusters by one:

```
names<-gsub("ranch","",names)
names<-gsub("et al","",names)
d  <- adist(names,ignore.case=TRUE, costs=c(i=1,d=1,s=2))
rownames(d) <- names
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
rect.hclust(hc,k=7)
```

[image]

Although there are methods to let the data sort out the best number of clusters instead of manually trying to pick the number, I found that it was easiest to use trial and error, although there is information [here about that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/1203041).

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion by Roman in the comments on the natural language processing is probably the best place to start. But for a back-of-the-envelope type of approach you can look at the distance in terms of ascii code:

```
mynames = c("abcd efghijkl mn","zbcd efghijkl mn","bbcd efghijkl mn","erqe")
asc <- function(x) { strtoi(charToRaw(x),16L) }
namesToChar= sapply(mynames, asc)
maxLength= max(unlist(lapply(namesToChar,length)))
namesToChar =lapply(namesToChar, function(x) { c(x, rep(-1, times = maxLength-length(x) )) } )
namesToChar = do.call("rbind",namesToChar)
dist(namesToChar,method="euclidean")
dist(namesToChar,method="canberra")
```

Though it seems to give OK enough numbers for the sample,

```
> dist(namesToChar,method="manhattan")
                 abcd efghijkl mn zbcd efghijkl mn bbcd efghijkl mn
zbcd efghijkl mn               25                                  
bbcd efghijkl mn                1               24                 
erqe                          257              274              256
```

this approach suffers from the fact that there does not seem to be an adequate distance method for the `dist` function for what you want to do. An element-wise binary comparison followed by a more standard distance perhaps ('manhattan' seems closest to your needs)? You could always implement that yourself of course. Also the `-1` fill out is a hack here, you would need to replace that with the average ascii code of your sample if you decide to go this route.

For a similarity score versus the overall population you can take inverse of the average distance against each other word.