# agrep function of R is not working for text matching

Tags: r, text-mining, agrep

I am trying to match string using `agrep` function of `R`. I do not understand, why it's not returning any value. I am looking a solution which will give  closed match of the given text. In the given example it should show `"ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa"`

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance.

```
x= as.vector(c("sharda stone crusher prop roopa","sharda stone crusher prop rupa"))
agrep("ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa devi",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 0.1, useBytes = FALSE)
character(0)
```

Comment: because you're trying to match the whole expression `"ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa"`, try `agrep("rupa",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 0.1, useBytes = FALSE)
` why are you using `agrep` and not `grep` ?

Comment: But I am looking for the method which matches whole expression. Is there a way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: So it is returning no value.. as the whole expression is not contains in your vector.. show the output you're looking for... (by editing your response)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, edited me question. I want to get the closest match of the given expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of your `max.distance` parameter. see `?agrep`.

for instance:

```
agrep("ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa devi",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 0.2, useBytes = FALSE)
"sharda stone crusher prop rupa"
agrep("ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa devi",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 0.25, useBytes = FALSE)
"sharda stone crusher prop roopa" "sharda stone crusher prop rupa" 
agrep("ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa devi",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 9, useBytes = FALSE)
"sharda stone crusher prop rupa"
agrep("ms sharda stone crusher prop rupa devi",x,ignore.case=T,value=T,max.distance = 10, useBytes = FALSE)
"sharda stone crusher prop roopa" "sharda stone crusher prop rupa"
```

If you want only the closest match see:
[best match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721883/agrep-only-return-best-matches)