# Why does agrep in R not find the best match?

Tags: r, agrep

I am attempting string matching in R using the agrep command.
However I am concerned that it stops when it finds a good match, rather than optimize to find the best one. Though it is possible my understanding of how it works is incorrect. My example below reproduces the problem, albeit crudely.

```
example1 <- c("height","weight")
example2 <- c("height","weight")

y <- c("","")
for( i in 1: 2 ){
x <- agrep(example1[i], example2, max.distance = 1, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE ) 
x <- paste0(x,"")
y[i] <- x
  }
```

As you will hopefully see, agrep has matched weight to height, when weight is the better match and also present.

Why is this?

Comment: The value `x` is a vector of two values, but only the first is assigned to `y` (you should have a warning), so only `height` is given

Comment: So x contains all matches that meet the criteria, and I am just choosing the first of these, which isn't necessarily the best match? 
Is there a way to extract just the best one?
At the moment I am having to do an exact match followed by a fuzzy match to get around the problem. However this example is not filling me with confidence for the rest of my fuzzy matches.

Comment: yes that's it. You might look at [this question for the best match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721883/agrep-only-return-best-matches/27090472)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adist (for generalized Levenshtein (edit) distance), with the following result ('height' from example1 best matches with height from example2 etc.):

```
adist(example1, example2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0

example2[apply(adist(example1, example2), 1, which.min)]
# [1] "height" "weight"
```